# How to know which user paid?

Tags: php

How can I know which user paid (via paypal) for my service using php?

I have a table in my database named users,containing the following rows:

```
ID, Username, email, IP, password
```

If the user have a different paypal email than the email he made a registration at my website, how can I know that *he* paid me and not someone else?

Comment: Use the PayPal API to know when you've been paid for what period of service, and track that in a database.

Comment: Make user proceed to checkout from your website and attach it to the UserID, for example, how about that?

Comment: yes but how can I connect the database user email: test@test.com with the email he paid: mike@mike.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Paypal payments for a while, but when you send the checkout details to Paypal I seem to remember you send a transaction ID (txn_id) or something similar, you just need to store that transaction ID next to the user in your database, when PayPal return the 'success' payment with the transaction ID, you know which user it was that paid.

You haven't said what method you're using to collect payments, but again I seem to remember Paypal's IPN (Instant Payment Notification) service is a good place to start;

Here's a link to some info on: [Paypal's IPN service](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro)

And also some: [code samples on how to integrate IPN](https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623)